# Can't find a referenced R File on the SEC Website?

Tags: database, dataframe, sec

I am attempting to understand the 2020q1 data set found here: https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets.html, 
and am using the reference documentation inside the 2020q1 folder as a “readme” file. The reference documentation specifies that 
within the Presentation (pre) data set, the “report” field is a numeric (integer) whose “value refers to the “R file” as posted 
on the EDGAR Web site.” I have found no such file after extensive search, and am left with no method of interpreting the “report” 
field and all associated data. Please link to the appropriate R File or guide me in the right direction for assistance if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So a point of clarification upfront, cause this confused me as well, the "R file" in question is not a script file of the [R language](https://www.r-project.org/about.html). Instead, it simply seems to be a report file that holds the formatted data.

So after digging deeper into the readme, I found the following detail in the description for the SUB.txt data.

> Note: To access the complete submission files for a given filing, please see the SEC EDGAR website.  The SEC website folder HTTP(s)://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{cik}/{accession}/ will always contain all the data sets for a given submission.  To assemble the folder address to any filing referenced in the SUB data set, simply substitute {cik} with the cik field and replace {accession} with the adsh field (after removing the dash character).  The following sample SQL Query provides an example of how to generate a list of addresses for filings contained in the SUB data set:
>
> ·          select name,form,period, 'http(s)://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/' + ltrim(str(cik,10))+'/' + replace(adsh,'-','')+'/'+instance as url from SUBM subm order by period desc, name

Therefore, it looks like we have to correlate each "adsh" submission ID with the "cik" company ID in order to get the link we are looking for.

Doing this for the first entry of pre.txt, we get an adsh value of "0001032208-20-000006". I simply searched through sub.txt with notepad and found its associated cik of "1032208" which belongs to "SEMPRA ENERGY". Therefore, we generate the following link: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1032208/000103220820000006

From there, we find a directory of files associated with the given submission. Inside is a collection of files with the prefix of "R". Simply clicking on them will open them in your browser, using the "report" and "line" fields, we can then correlate which file we want. Notice that we can add "*/R{number}.htm*" at the end of the link we generated to find this folder to get a given report number.

If you know what you are looking for, doing this by hand with "ctr+f" find functionality should be fine. Otherwise, you may want to open these docs in excel to generate the links for you.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.